# Managing Balkan Graph on mobile

Tags: mobile, orgchart

I realized an orgchart using BALKAN GRAPH(OrgChart JS), but when i open the application page on my phone browzer, i can't neither zoom or pan.
Can anyone help me on that issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Next of OrgChart JS version will support zoom and pan on mobile

Comment: Okey @BALKANGraph. Thank you, and when it's going to be launched?

Comment: Our plan is to release it tomorrow

Comment: Now OrgChart JS | BALKANGraph works on mobile